# Locating a point based on a condition

Tags: geometry, contest-math

C and D are two points on the same side of straight line AB. Find a point X on AB such       that the angles CXA and DXB are equal.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Do you need $X$ between $A$ and $B$ or only on the line $AB$?

Comment: I would guess only on AB. Consider the case where C is "far away" from A and B while D is "close".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I take the reflection of $D$ over line $AB$ as $D'$, then $X$ can be taken as the intersection of segment $AB$ and segment $CD'$. (I should have realised this)

---

**How I originally got this:**

By adding a coordinate system and flipping if necessary, assume $A$ is at origin and $B$ is at $(1,0)$. $C$ is at $(x_1,y_1)$ and D is at $(x_2,y_2)$, with $y_1$ and $y_2$ positive.

Let $X$ be a point at $(x, 0)$ on the line $AB$.

$$\begin{align*}
\cot\angle CXA = &\frac{x-x_1}{y_1}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}{x}\\
\cot\angle DXB =& \frac{x-x_2}{y_2}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}{(x-1)}
\end{align*}$$

If $X$ is limited to be on the segment $AB$, $0<x<1$, so the two $\operatorname{sgn}$'s above give different signs:

$$\begin{align*}
\cot\angle CXA =& \cot\angle DXB\\
\frac{x-x_1}{y_1} =& -\frac{x-x_2}{y_2}\\
x=& \frac{x_1y_2 + x_2y_1}{y_1+y_2}
\end{align*}$$

Then it leaves to be checked that such $x$ is between $0$ and $1$. This $x$ can be viewed as the $x$-coordinate which separates $CD$ by $y_1:y_2$.

---

If such limitation is lifted, then another case is $x<0$ or $x>1$. By similar reasoning as above,

$$x = \frac{x_1y_2 - x_2y_1}{y_2-y_1}$$

Depending on the sign of $y_2-y_1$, this $x$ can be seen as the $x$-coordinate which separates $CD$ by $-y_1:y_2$ or $y_1:-y_2$. And so such $X$ is where line $CD$ intersects line $AB$, if the intersection is outside segment $AB$. This is what @DavidH suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Does the intersection of $CD'$ with the line $AB$ belongs to the segment $AB$?

Comment: If the intersection is not within segment $AB$, then such intersection does not qualify as $X$. Only intersection of segments counts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming the line CD is not parallel to AB, let X be the point of intersection of the two lines.

Note, the special case that CD is parallel to AB still has to be considered.

Comment: This does not work if $CD$ intersects $AB$ at $X$ between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Sigur Indeed. But that's why this is a hint.

Comment: But, since the OP wants $X$ on the segment $AB$, I'm not able to see how your post is a hint if it does not work on that case.

Comment: @Sigur Ah, I see what you mean. I didn't notice that he apparently wants X on the segment. However, I don't believe he is correct in that interpretation of the problem, since then there wouldn't be a solution for many choices of C and D.

Comment: Well, your solution works very well if $X$ is not between $A$ and $B$. Otherwise, I agree that always there is a solution.